# Run jar file get java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql

Tags: java

I compiled the jar file from eclipse (package required lib...), and then when I run it, it gives me the SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql, which doesn't happen when I run code inside eclipse.

I see a lot of people point out the issue might caused by naming one of the package as "java.*", but I double-checked that there is no package that is named as "java.{somthing}".

Here is full error trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1005)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:545)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:453)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:446)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdJdkSerializers.all(StdJdkSerializers.java:55)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.<clinit>(BasicSerializerFactory.java:93)
    ... 12 more
```

OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.2; 
Java Version: 9.0.4; 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11); 
Eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

P.S. I didn't use mysql or any other sql driver.

**Edit:**
When I run the code inside eclipse, it works perfectly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the code for the file that is causing the issue? It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without something to go off of.

Comment: Are you creating a Runnable JAR via Eclipse ?

Comment: @AnuragDwivedi yes, I created the runnable jar via eclipse

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868490/8656457).

Comment: @Fishy  from the output I couldn't tell which code is causing error. It works inside eclipse without any issue.

Comment: @AnuragDwivedi Hi, it works lol. Could you answer it so I can mark you as correct. I work with eclipse for a while but still confused about extract and package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select **Extract required libaries** while setting the library handling option in Jar generator. :)